# Smooth atlas on $ \mathrm{O}(V, \beta)=\{A \in \mathrm{GL}(V) \mid \beta(A u, A v)=\beta(u, v) \quad \forall u, v \in V\} $

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Suppose that $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $\beta: V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a nondegenerate bi-linear paring on $V$ which is either symmetric or anti-symmetric. Let $$
\mathrm{O}(V, \beta)=\{A \in \mathrm{GL}(V) \mid \beta(A u, A v)=\beta(u, v) \quad \forall u, v \in V\}
$$
$$
\mathrm{R}=\{A \in \operatorname{End}(V) \mid A+\mathrm{I} \in \mathrm{GL}(V)\} .
$$
I am trying to show $\left\{\left(U_{A}, \phi_{A}\right) \mid A \in \mathrm{O}(V, \beta)\right\}$ is a smooth atlas on $\mathrm{O}(V, \beta)$ where for $A \in \mathrm{O}(V, \beta)$
$$U_{A}:=\{A \circ B \mid B \in \mathrm{R} \cap \mathrm{O}(V, \beta)\}$$
and $\phi_{A}: U_{A} \rightarrow \mathrm{R} \cap \mathfrak{s o}(V, \beta)$ denotes the map defined by $$\phi_{A}(B):=\left(A^{-1} \circ B\right)^{\mathrm{c}}$$
Where $\mathfrak{s o}$ is the (-1) eigenspace of the transposition map.

I've already proven that $R$ is an open subset of End$(V)$, the Cayley transform $A^{\mathrm{c}}:=(A-\mathrm{I})(A+\mathrm{I})^{-1}$ is a differentiable involution on $R$ and it restricts to a homeomorphism between  $\mathrm{R} \cap \mathrm{O}(V, \beta)$ and $\mathrm{R} \cap \mathfrak{s o}(V, \beta)$.

Comment: Do you necessarily have to find atlases? We have that ${\rm O}(V,\beta)$ is the stabilizer of $\beta \in [V^*]^{\otimes 2}$ under the smooth Lie group action ${\rm GL}(V) \circlearrowright [V^*]^{\otimes 2}$ given by pull-back. Stabilizers are closed subgroups of ${\rm GL}(V)$ and hence embedded Lie subgroups.